# Excel Change the Color of the Comment Indicator

Tags: excel, excel-formula, format

My issue is that we have a conditional format that changes a cell fill color to red as an error indicator when the cells value is less than 0.  Because of a specific situation this actually isn't an error, but for consistency I don't want to change the conditional format or add any text in another area of the sheet, but when I add a comment the normal indicator for a comment is the red flag in the top right which can't be seen with the red fill.

Is there a way for me to change the comment indicator flag for a specific comment?

Comment: [This](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2253-excel-change-comment-indicator-color.html) can show you how to change the comment flag's color, but what you should do is just change the conditional formatting rule to take into account whatever your exception is.

Comment: Thanks for the link!